# Apache not working - 500 error

Tags: installation, apache2

Fresh new install of Ubuntu fresh new install of apache2. Apache not working, where should I start? It's installed, it restarts properly it just doesn't show anything in the browser but a 500 error:

> HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was
>   encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: you could check /var/log/apache2/error.log and see what the problem is

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

> where should i start ?

You should start with the apache error log file: /var/log/apache2/error.log

Answer (score 0):

You could also give more information on what your doing to view the server.

When you're in the browser do you view http://127.0.0.1/ or http://localhost/?

Try both, if one works and the other not your problem is not with Apache but with the networking settings.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to setup one site on 127.0.0.1 as localhost or multiple sites?

Have you followed all the steps here including troubleshooting? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

And there is more troubleshooting info here https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/httpd.html